# Nodes and Pagination is not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am making a pagination but the problem is about get the values of pages. I can get first page but I cannot get other pages. When I do `?page=2` page 2 does not loads and it shows page 1 again.

Example of this is: I have 15 articles but because of limit(perPage) it just shows 5 articles for per page. And I can get just first 5 articles. I want to get other pages just like this ===> `?page=2`

But I couldnt understand why it is not working.

**This is my app.js:**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var perPage = 5
  var page = req.params.page

  Metin
  .find({})
  .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
  .limit(perPage)
  .exec(function(err, metins) {
      Metin.count().exec(function(err, count) {
          if (err) return next(err)
          res.render('index', {
              current: page,
              pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
              metins: metins,
          })
      })
  })
});
```

Comment: Check [this](https://codeforgeek.com/server-side-pagination-using-node-and-mongo/) and conver parameter value to int because by default it is string.

Comment: you should use `req.query.page`.

Comment: Also you should try to use a fallack to page 1 if `page` query is not sent. Something like `var page = req.params.page || 1`

Comment: Yes it worked thanks. If you want to get a like on your post you can post then I can like it